# Unable to enter data on edittext fields of appium

Tags: android, mobile, appium

I am entering data on these checkboxes. The script runs fine but data does not enters. Check the code below:

`List<WebElement>pincode = driver.findElements(By.id("com.theentertainerme.entertainer:id/pin_code_round)"));`

```
    pincode.get(0).sendKeys("0");
    pincode.get(1).sendKeys("0");
    pincode.get(2).sendKeys("0");
    pincode.get(3).sendKeys("0");
```

Check UI of screen 
[Image added is of UiAutomatorViewer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a4zI0.png)
Please help me out on this.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please read the user guidelines on how to ask a good question before posting a question (http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) Thank You

Comment: They are not checkboxes right?Edit the question

Answer (score 0):

Instead of doing like that you can enter the four digits by using android keycodes.

```
driver.pressKeyCode(AndroidKeyCode.KEYCODE_1);
driver.pressKeyCode(AndroidKeyCode.KEYCODE_1);
driver.pressKeyCode(AndroidKeyCode.KEYCODE_1);
driver.pressKeyCode(AndroidKeyCode.KEYCODE_1);
```

This will enter all 1's in the four fields.